# Expected determinant of a random symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, uniform-distribution, random-matrices, symmetric-matrices

The three distinct entries of a $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrix are drawn from the uniform distribution over $[-60, 60]$. What is the expected determinant of the matrix?

I assume it is $0$ but I am not good at proving it efficiently. Thanks.

Comment: the three distinct entries?

Comment: If the random matrix was not symmetric then the expectation would be $0$ due to the fact that the matrix distribution is invariant under swapping the rows.  That distribution is also invariant under negating one row, which is another reason the expectation is $0$ in that case.  However, restricting to symmetric matrices breaks both of these symmetries (swapping rows of a symmetric matrix does not give a symmetric matrix, and same for negating one row of a symmetric matrix).  As the answer shows, the expectation is strictly negative.

Answer (score 9):

Let the matrix be in the form of

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ b & d \end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant is $ad-b^2$.

Assuming the $3$ entries to be independent.
\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[ad-b^2]&=\mathbb{E}[ad]-\mathbb{E}[b^2]\\&=\mathbb{E}[a]\mathbb{E}[d]-\mathbb{E}[b^2] \\
&=-(\mathbb E[b^2]-\mathbb{E}[b]^2)\\
&=-Var(b)\end{align}

Comment: ... i.e, using formula $\dfrac{1}{12}(b-a)^2$ for the variance (see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous))) gives the final result $-\dfrac{1}{12}(120^2)=-1200.$

Comment: I do not understand this solution that's why I gave a downvote? What is the final result? Why are you guys upvoting it?

Comment: can you elaborate on which part is not clear to you?

Comment: I dont understand entirely. I'd be glad if you can elaborate you solution? What is the final result?

Comment: are you having difficulty with the variance?

Comment: Ok it'd be better if you write Var(b) = Variance(b) explicitly. We did not mention Variance so far and then you write Var.